# Django widget overwrites error_messages on forms.py

Tags: django-forms

This is super wierd, if i put the widget to setup the field for a password field it will show me the input type password but the errors changes to ( This Field is Required ) instead of ( Please type your username or password) here is my code below. any ideas of how to overcome this?

```
class loginForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = user

    fields = ('username', 'password')


        error_messages = {
            'username': {
                'required': ('Please enter your username'),
            },

            'password': {
                'required': ('Please type your password'),
            },
        },

        widgets = {
            'password': forms.PasswordInput(),
        }
```

How it looks without, and does not show asterisk for password just plain text

[image]

How it looks with widget, here it hides the text for password field but does not show the error_messages properly as set in the error_messages dictionary.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the answer is to add PasswordInput from django.forms

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm, PasswordInput
from models import user


class loginForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = user

        fields = ('username', 'password')

        error_messages = {
            'username': {
            'required': ('Please enter your username'),
        },

        'password': {
        'required': ('Please type your password'),
        },
    }

    widgets = {
        'password': PasswordInput(),
    }
```